# How can I collect greenplum monitor metrics without gpcc and gpperfmon

Tags: grafana, monitor, greenplum

I want to use collect greenplum monitor metrics and show it with grafana. How can I collect greenplum monitor metrics without gpcc and gpperfmon, such as cpu, memory, waiting queries, slow queries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Greenplum supports SNMP which you can collect metrics from using [snmp_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter)
then scrape them with Prometheus and visualize them in Grafana